# Problems with small C++ bitset code

Tags: c++, bitset

I have tried to write the following code into my compiler and compile it:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

void binary(int a)
{
 cout << bitset<8>(a).to_string() << endl;
}

int main()
{

binary(16);

system("pause");
return 0;    
}
```

It should give me a binary output but I keep getting an error:

```
In function `void binary(int)': 
no matching function for call to `std::bitset<8u>::to_string()'
```

I am new to C++ and dont really know what this means, please help me.

Comment: This compiles and runs fine on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/qcBEoS)).

Comment: nope your code [does compile and run successfully](http://ideone.com/97plfJ). Nothing is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2):

I think older versions of `bitset::to_string<T>()` takes a template argument.  So this should work:

```
cout << bitset<8>(a).to_string<char>() << endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

bitset don't have a to_string method (stl does not use to_string anyway). You should iterate on values yourself.

Comment: Is this not a case of "what compiler/C++library, and what settings"? If the compiler supports C++11 (or sufficiently late C++0x), it should work fine, but with default settings, it wont?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string it does exist even before C++11, although with less defaults/flexibility.